# How do you release memory in xcode 4.2?

Tags: xcode

In xcode 4.2 I have found it very frustrating because you can't use:

```
-(void)dealloc {
[label release]; //'release' is unavailable
[super dealloc]; //'dealloc' is forbidden in automatic reference counting
}
```

Is there another way because autorelease and other deallocs don't work either.

Comment: ... you don't. Unless you have your project using manual memory management.

Comment: so i wouldn't get a memory warning even if i did not release memory?

Comment: I can't say off the top of my head. Check the docs on that, I do not think memory warnings have gone away, especially with the iPhone 3GS still on the market.

Comment: Just found out it does everything for you automatically!

Comment: If you get a memory warning, you may still need to decrease your memory usage. To do so, you might let go of an image you're holding onto by doing `myImageIvar = nil;`, or you might clear out a cache by doing `[myCache removeAllObjects];`. ARC won't handle memory warnings for you—it just ensures that if you have a pointer to an object, that object is retained, and that when you remove a pointer to an object, the object is released.

Comment: So I should set things holding large files to nil?

Comment: If you would have called `[myThing release]` upon receiving a memory warning, then you should now call `myThing = nil;` instead. That's all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Xcode 4.2 introduces "Automatic Reference Counting" (aka ARC). This is a compiler feature that basically inserts the retain and release calls for you. Under ARC, if you have a pointer to an object, you're retaining it. When your pointer goes out of scope, or is reassigned to point to another object, the original object is released. It's really nice.

So, in short, you just remove all the calls to `retain`, `release`, and `autorelease`, and the compiler will do the right thing *for* you.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on Automatic Reference Counting.  If you write your code properly, you don't need to do any of that anymore.

If you want to use old code without converting, disable ARC.  put `-fno-objc-arc` in the compiler flags for any source modules you don't want to use ARC.

joe

Comment: Would it matter if i didn't release memory?